# Рисование прямоугольников и сохранение полученной картинки в файл

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, gdi

### Код

```
public class Shape
{
    public int X { get; set; }

    public int Y { get; set; }

    public int Width { get; set; }

    public int Height { get; set; }

}

public class ShapeRender
{
    public void Render()
    {
        var shapes = new List<Shape>
        {
            new Shape
            {
                X = 2530,
                Y = 2041,
                Width = 1890,
                Height = 621
            },
            new Shape
            {
                X = 6516,
                Y = 1944,
                Width = 1890,
                Height = 816
            }
        };

        // Code to draw shapes and save into image file.
        //...
    }
}
```

---

### Задача

В выше описанном коде, в методе `ShapeRender()`, создаются объекты `Shape`, которые необходимо отрисовать на такой плоскости:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И сохранить полученное изображение в файл jpg, png или bmp.

---

### Дополнительное описание

Единицы задаваемые для свойств `X`, `Y`, `Width`, `Height` условные.

---

### Вопрос

Что из инструментария .NET использовать? Я не мало порылся в пространстве имен `System.Drawing`, но так и не смог соорентироваться.

Comment: Ну а что вы глядели? Там где то вроде есть Graphics, который умеет рисовать. Ну, или вы можете это на канвасе wpf изобразить. Ну или вручную в массив нарисовать. Больше по памяти ничего не лезет в голову :)

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что с репутацией 2к Вы не нашли в Интернете примеров рисования прямоугольника в .NET?

Comment: @Igor, конечно сказать так будет не правда. Вот один из примеров на который я наткнулся  https://bit.ly/2wRYNlE. И у меня не получается распрастранить это на свой случай. Везде акцент делается на Windows.Forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Полагаю, что Вы сможете из этого сделать отрисовку списка прямоугольников.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

...

private static Image CreateImageWithRectangle()
{
  Image img = new Bitmap(1000, 500);

  using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(img))
  {
    gr.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red, 2), 100, 100, 800, 300);
  }

  return img;
}

...

Image img = CreateImageWithRectangle();
img.Save(@"C:\temp\image.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: Значения _100, 100_, которые принимает `DrawRectangle()`, это ведь координаты X и Y, а что за единицы измерения ? Это ведь не пиксели?

Comment: @adamshakhabov это текущие логические координаты рисовальной поверхности. В данном примере они совпадают с пикселями.

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно отображение, то вот вам на WPF.

Кладём в окне такой `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" Background="White" x:Name="Host">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}"
                       Stroke="DarkGray" StrokeThickness="1"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Добавляем прямоугольники:

```
var shapes = new List<Shape>
{
    new Shape
    {
        X = 500, Y = 200,
        Width = 600, Height = 450
    },
    new Shape
    {
        X = 100, Y = 500,
        Width = 200, Height = 600
    }
};
DataContext = shapes;
```

Вуаля, у нас есть отображение.

Чтобы сохранить в файл, используйте вот что:

```
var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(
    (int)Host.ActualWidth, (int)Host.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
rtb.Render(Host);

var jpg = new JpegBitmapEncoder() { Frames = { BitmapFrame.Create(rtb) } };
using (var f = File.Create(@"d:\testrender.jpg"))
    jpg.Save(f);
```

---

Если нужен рендеринг на сервере, можно обойтись без визуальных элементов:

```
var shapes = new List<Shape>
{
    new Shape
    {
        X = 500, Y = 200,
        Width = 600, Height = 450
    },
    new Shape
    {
        X = 100, Y = 500,
        Width = 200, Height = 600
    }
};

var totalW = shapes.Max(s => s.X + s.Width) + 10;
var totalH = shapes.Max(s => s.Y + s.Height) + 10;

var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(totalW, totalH, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
var visual = new DrawingVisual();

var pen = new Pen(Brushes.DarkGray, 1);
using (var r = visual.RenderOpen())
{
    r.DrawRectangle(Brushes.White, null, new Rect(0, 0, totalW, totalH));
    foreach (var shape in shapes)
        r.DrawRectangle(null, pen, new Rect(shape.X, shape.Y, shape.Width, shape.Height));
}

rtb.Render(visual);

var jpg = new JpegBitmapEncoder() { Frames = { BitmapFrame.Create(rtb) } };
using (var f = File.Create(@"d:\testrender.jpg"))
    jpg.Save(f);
```

Comment: Мне нужно сделать библиотеку, которую будет использовать проект ASP.NET Core. Но я так полагаю предложенный вариант все же должен подойти?

Comment: Этого я не знаю, но если вам нужен серверный код, зачем вам отображение?

Comment: После создание таких картинок я должен отправлять их на машинное обучение, алгоритму который работает с изображением.

Comment: @adamshakhabov: Добавил ещё код